# Mysql Update one column of multiple rows in one query

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, temp-tables

I've looked over all of the related questions i've find, but couldn't get one which will answer mine.

i got a table like this:

```
id | name | age | active | ...... | ... |
```

where "id" is the primary key, and the ... meaning there are something like 30 columns.
the "active" column is of tinyint type.

My task:

Update ids 1,4,12,55,111 (those are just an example, it can be 1000 different id in total) with active = 1 in a single query.

I did:

```
UPDATE table SET active = 1 WHERE id IN (1,4,12,55,111)
```

- its  inside a transaction, cause i'm updating something else in this process.
- the engine is InnoDB

---

My problem:

Someone told me that doing such a query is equivalent to 5 queries at execution, cause the IN will translate to the a given number of OR, and run them one after another.

eventually, instead of 1 i get N which is the number in the IN.

he suggests to create a temp table, insert all the new values in it, and then update by join.

Does he right? both of the equivalency and performance.

---

What do you suggest? i've thought INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE UPDATE will help but i don't have all the data for the row, only it id, and that i want to set active = 1 on it.

Maybe this query is better?

```
UPDATE table SET
active = CASE
WHEN id='1' THEN '1'
WHEN id='4' THEN '1'
WHEN id='12' THEN '1'
WHEN id='55' THEN '1'
WHEN id='111' THEN '1'
ELSE active END
WHERE campaign_id > 0;  //otherwise it throws an error about updating without where clause in safe mode, and i don't know if i could toggle safe mode off.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes he is right or Use Exists.  Update table set active = 1 where Exists(Select 1 from table2 where ...)

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around.  `OR` can sometimes be turned into `IN`.  `IN` is then efficiently executed, especially if there is an index on the column.  If you have 1000 entries in the `IN`, it will do 1000 probes into the table based on `id`.

If you are running a new enough version of MySQL, I think you can do `EXPLAIN EXTENDED UPDATE ...OR...; SHOW WARNINGS;` to see this conversion;

The `UPDATE CASE...` will probably tediously check each and every row.

It would probably be better on other users of the system if you broke the `UPDATE` up into multiple `UPDATEs`, each having 100-1000 rows.  [*More on chunking*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) .

Where did you get the ids in the first place?  If it was via a `SELECT`, then perhaps it would be practical to combine it with the `UPDATE` to make it one step instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

I think below is better because it uses primary key.

```
UPDATE table SET active = 1 WHERE id<=5
```

Comment: 1-5 is just an example, id could be any set of numbers , for example: (1,10,23,44,51), i'll edit the question so it will be clearer